# Draw multiple squares in a Java JFrame and access each single one of them?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe

I basically want to divide a 300 by 300 JFrame window into like 30 squares (without drawing them all separately) and be able to access each of the squares (maybe put them into an array/arraylist/stack/vector/etc). Is this possible without writing drawRect(x, y, width, height) 30 times? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to have object references to each square (so you can put them into some collection structure), what do you want to do with the boxes? Do they have content that needs to get drawn onto the Canvas? Are they `JComponent`s? Do you want to use a flyweight pattern similar to how `JList`, `JTable` does rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep your components in an ArrayList and get use of GridLayout
and the following snippet:

```
getContentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(x,y));
```

where x and y denotes the number of rows and columns respectively.
After that you can add components to the content of your JFrame object.

Sample code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        MyFrame myframe = new MyFrame();
        myframe.setSize( 300, 300 );
        myframe.setResizable( false );
        myframe.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        myframe.setLayout( new GridLayout(3,3) );

        Container container = myframe.getContentPane();
        ArrayList < JPanel > components = new ArrayList < JPanel >();
        JPanel temp = null;

        // Populating Arraylist object.
        for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
        {
            temp = new JPanel();
            temp.setSize( 100,100 );
            components.add( temp );
            container.add(temp);
        }

        myframe.pack();
        myframe.setVisible( true );

        // Accessing components via index.
        components.get( 5 ).setBackground( Color.BLUE );
        components.get( 8 ).setBackground( Color.GREEN );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use a layout manager

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Comment: use the gridlayout as superdeporter suggests using a layout manager.

Answer (score 2):

Why not go for a JTable instead of this ?